# How to create a fixed header on a mobile browser

Tags: header, jquery-mobile, css-position, mobile-browser

I'm looking for a JavaScript/jQuery plugin which allows to use a fixed header on mobile browser.

[iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) seems to be the most popular solution but I was interested in a plugin that isn't constantly calculating the position of the header while scrolling.

The idea is the same used by [jQueryMobile fixed toolbars](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html), while the user is scrolling the header disappears and only reappears after finishing scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more simple than what you think.
I use this code:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <h1>Fixed Header!</h1>
</div>
```

See more info:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html